# How to Validate Drop down value in playwright

Tags: typescript, automation, playwright

I'm trying to validate the dropdown value I selected. I'm using this for the Playwright tool. I wrote a code for that validation but I got an error. anyone knows how to fix this error and how to write this in typescript using this $eval.
thank you.

```
test('testing Drop Down',async ({page}) => {
    await page.goto('https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/dropdown');
    await page.selectOption('#dropdown','1');
    const selectvalue = await page.$eval('#dropdown',(element)=>element.value);
   expect (selectvalue).toContain('1');


Error: expect(received).toContain(expected) // indexOf

Expected substring: "1"
Received string:    "select"

  22 |    // const alloption=await option1.$$('option');
  23 |    await page.locator('select').selectOption('1');
> 24 |    await expect('select').toContain('1')
     |                           ^
  25 |
  26 |
```

Comment: Did you try `toHaveValue`?

Comment: See below latest approach - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77203521

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issues on that page sometimes it is going faster and pick select as default, even the code after is changing the dd to some other values. So you can use hard wait.

```
page.waitforTimeout(100)
```

or this:

```
selectedDDtext = page.locator('#dropdown [selected="selected"]');
texttoVerify = selectedDDtext.innerText();
```

Or for value:

```
   await this.page.$eval<string, HTMLSelectElement>('select[id="dropdown"]',(ele) => ele.value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Latest recommended approach using [toHaveValue](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locatorassertions#locator-assertions-to-have-value) per playwright docs:

```
await expect(locator).toHaveValue('1');
```

Which would assert that the selector has the given text.

Comment: I think you omitted 'expect()' for toHaveText().

Answer (score 0):

May use evaluate
https://playwright.dev/docs/next/api/class-worker#worker-evaluate

```
locator.evaluate("el => el.options[el.selectedIndex].value")
```